# how to check webservices on a production server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

On the ASP.NET server (production), I am told to use the web service that is written by some other person.

Question is how do I find out what webservices were deployed on the production server. All I am told is to make a call using "CheckFile" (which I believe is a part of the web service). I went to the Inetpub folder to see if there is any folder that has these webservices but there is none?

Sorry I am doing this first time and hence many questions,

My end goal is to use these webservices in my ASP.NET application and call those functions such as "CheckFile" and others from this webservice.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a simple question to your co-worker could solve this.

Comment: @Ek0nomik: I am working alone at this moment. If you know, please reply. I know it is a simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree ask your co-worker if you have one.Else if you have access to old asp.net app then right clik on project  and click on service reference tab it will show web services in that .net app.

Comment: :Did you meant opening any .net application using visual studio and then checking 'services' tab? I don't have visual studio on production server.

Comment: No I meant trying to open any old project they have and right click on solution explorer and click add web reference to see if you can find something. OR try http://servername/virtualdirectoryname/service1.asmx   in you r case find for .asmx files in local machine and Production server